# spring data cassandra maps null as empty List

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have the following dto object:

```
public class Data {

    @PrimaryKey private EntityKey key;

    @Column("r_proposals")
    private List<Integer> rProposals;

}
```

now, when I try to serialise this object in cassandra with rProposals set to null (using cassandraTemplate::insert), it gets stored as empty list:

[image]

does anybody know how to override this behaviour and set collection to null if null was passed in?

we use spring boot 2.4.3; spring data cassandra 3.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra does not distinguish between an empty collection and a null.

When inserting, it doesn't matter which one you use, it will end up stored in the exact same fashion at the database level.

When reading, most drivers – including the one used by Spring Boot – usually prefer to use an empty collection rather than a null, to avoid NPEs.

So in short, this behavior is normal and there should be no reason for you to be worried about it.